How to make the windows icon bigger than 16x16?
I am having a problem not being able to make the window icon bigger than 16x16. It is awfully too small.
import os
import sys
import win32gui
import win32con
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QSlider
)


class Shax0(QMainWindow):
    """Shax0 main application with PyWin32 native title bar"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # Define the base path for resources
        self.base_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "playback")

        # Central widget
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        # Main vertical layout
        self.vBoxLayout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)

        # Create cover art label with updated style
        self.coverArtLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.coverArtLabel.setText("shax0")
        self.coverArtLabel.setStyleSheet("""
            background-color: #ECEFF4;  /* Slightly lighter gray color for cover art */
            border-radius: 15px;  /* Rounded corners for cover art */
            color: black;  /* Black text color */
            font-size: 24px;  /* Larger font size */
            font-family: 'Mononoki';  /* Mononoki font */
            font-weight: bold;
        """)
        self.coverArtLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.coverArtLabel.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)  # Make cover art expand

        # Media control bar with track navigation
        self.mediaControlBar = self.createMediaControlBar()

        # Add spacers and widgets
        self.vBoxLayout.addSpacerItem(QSpacerItem(0, 10, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding))
        self.vBoxLayout.addWidget(self.coverArtLabel, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.vBoxLayout.addSpacerItem(QSpacerItem(0, 10, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding))
        self.vBoxLayout.addLayout(self.mediaControlBar)

        # Set up window properties
        self.setWindowTitle("shax0")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(os.path.join(self.base_path, "gt.png")))

        # Set initial window size and center
        self.resize(400, 300)  # Adjusted window size for compact layout
        self.centerWindow()

        # Apply native Windows title bar
        self.enableNativeTitleBar()

        # Apply a translucent effect (for mini player)
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.9)  # Make the window slightly translucent
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QWidget {
                background-color: #D8DEE9;  /* Slightly gray color for the window background */
                color: #2E3440;  /* Darker text color for readability */
                border-radius: 15px;  /* Rounded corners for the entire window */
                padding: 10px;
            }
            QLabel {
                color: black;  /* Black text for cover art */
            }
            QPushButton {
                background-color: transparent;  /* Transparent background for buttons */
                color: #4C566A;  /* Darker text color for buttons */
                border: none;  /* Remove button border */
                padding: 10px;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
            QPushButton:hover {
                background-color: #A3BE8C;  /* Lighter Nord color for hover state */
            }
            QPushButton:pressed {
                background-color: #88C0D0;  /* Slightly darker color for pressed state */
            }
            QSlider {
                background-color: #E5E9F0; /* Background of the slider */
                height: 6px;
                border: none; /* Remove border */
                border-radius: 3px; /* Rounded corners */
            }
            QSlider::groove:horizontal {
                background-color: #D8DEE9;
                height: 6px;
                border-radius: 3px;
            }
            QSlider::handle:horizontal {
                background-color: #4C566A; /* Dark handle */
                border-radius: 6px;
                width: 14px;
                height: 14px;
            }
        """)

        # State for the shuffle button (0: Shuffle, 1: Repeat, 2: Repeat One)
        self.current_state = 0

    def enableNativeTitleBar(self):
        """Enable the native Windows title bar using PyWin32."""
        hwnd = self.winId().__int__()
        style = win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_STYLE)
        style = style | win32con.WS_CAPTION | win32con.WS_THICKFRAME
        win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_STYLE, style)
        win32gui.SetWindowPos(
            hwnd, None, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            win32con.SWP_NOMOVE | win32con.SWP_NOSIZE | win32con.SWP_NOZORDER | win32con.SWP_FRAMECHANGED
        )

    def createMediaControlBar(self):
        """Create a vertical layout for media controls with icons and track navigation."""
        mediaControlBar = QVBoxLayout()  # Vertical layout for two rows

        # First row: Track Navigation (progress bar, no time numbers)
        trackNavigationLayout = QHBoxLayout()  # Horizontal layout for progress bar only
        self.progressBar = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.progressBar.setRange(0, 100)
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)

        trackNavigationLayout.addWidget(self.progressBar)

        # Second row: Buttons (play, rewind, stop, forward, shuffle, repeat, wave, terminal)
        buttonLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        buttons = [
            ("play.png", "Play"),
            ("rwd.png", "Rewind"),
            ("stop.png", "Stop"),
            ("fwd.png", "Forward"),
            ("shuffle.png", "Shuffle/Repeat/Repeat One"),
            ("wave.png", "Wave"),
            ("terminal.png", "Terminal")
        ]

        for icon_name, tooltip in buttons:
            button = self.createIconButton(icon_name, tooltip)
            if button:  # Only add the button if the icon exists
                buttonLayout.addWidget(button)

        # Add both rows to the media control bar
        mediaControlBar.addLayout(trackNavigationLayout)
        mediaControlBar.addLayout(buttonLayout)

        return mediaControlBar

    def createIconButton(self, icon_name, tooltip):
        """Create a QPushButton with an icon."""
        icon_path = os.path.join(self.base_path, icon_name)
        if os.path.exists(icon_path):
            button = QPushButton()
            button.setIcon(QIcon(icon_path))
            button.setToolTip(tooltip)
            button.setStyleSheet("font-size: 14px; padding: 5px;")
            # Connect the button to a slot that cycles the state for shuffle button
            if icon_name == "shuffle.png":
                button.clicked.connect(self.cycleState)
            return button
        else:
            print(f"Icon not found at: {icon_path}")  # Debug log
            # Optionally, set a default or error icon
            button = QPushButton(tooltip)
            button.setStyleSheet("font-size: 14px; color: red; padding: 5px;")
            return button

    def cycleState(self):
        """Cycle through Shuffle, Repeat, and Repeat One."""
        # Cycle state: 0 -> Shuffle, 1 -> Repeat, 2 -> Repeat One
        self.current_state = (self.current_state + 1) % 3

        if self.current_state == 0:  # Shuffle
            self.updateButtonState("shuffle.png", "Shuffle")
        elif self.current_state == 1:  # Repeat
            self.updateButtonState("repeat.png", "Repeat")
        elif self.current_state == 2:  # Repeat One
            self.updateButtonState("r1.png", "Repeat One")

    def updateButtonState(self, icon_name, tooltip):
        """Update button icon and tooltip."""
        button = self.sender()  # Get the button that was clicked
        icon_path = os.path.join(self.base_path, icon_name)
        if os.path.exists(icon_path):
            button.setIcon(QIcon(icon_path))
            button.setToolTip(tooltip)

    def centerWindow(self):
        """Center the window on the screen."""
        screen = self.screen().geometry()
        size = self.geometry()
        self.move(
            (screen.width() - size.width()) // 2,
            (screen.height() - size.height()) // 2
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Shax0()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


Using pywin32 and pyside6 to make my own titlebar without qfluentwidgets.
I have tried custom titlebars but it didn't work and the customs close buttons looks fake, so I'm using pywin32 for the windows style ones.
Please help. It's 16x16 and the icon in the titlebar is too small. How to make it bigger without breaking the titlebar?

The title bar is controlled by the OS and the icon size is based on the title bar height, which is eventually defined by user settings. AFAIK, there's no API to alter the title bar appearance, it may be possible to extend the client frame through DWM and then draw into it, but I sincerely don't know how (and if) it could be done in a reliable way.

so the only other thing to do is to draw the height bigger. then update the icon and itll match the size?

No. As the link above explains, by removing the standard frame the automatic drawing of the icon and title is lost, so it's up to you to draw both; remember, though, that that area is not accessible by Qt, so it must be rendered using DWM capabilities. Note that Qt developers are working on adding the ability to extend the client area for platforms that support it (see the related report, which already has some code submissions); if approved, it may be introduced in 6.9 (march 2025).

is there anyway to get the qfluentwidgets titlebar look wat do they use to reproduce their window 11 style titlebars

I'm not sure, but after a quick look at their code it just seems that they imitate the window 11 style by using custom drawing.
